# How to cut circle into $n$ parts (all cuts are parallel to each other) so that each chunk is the same area (i.e. $\pi r^2/n$)?

Tags: integration, geometry, circles

I have been working this problem for a few hours today, but I'm stuck. I started working on a case where $n = 3$:

Let the radius of the circle be centered at $(0,0)$, with a radius $r$. The equation of the circle, obviously, is $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, and solving for $y$, $y = \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$.

I took a look at the vertical segments $x = +d$, and $x=-d$, so that the areas to the left of $-d$, in between $-d$ and $d$, and to the right of $d$ are equal. Therefore, the integral of $\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ over $[-d, d]$ = $\frac{\pi r^2}{6}$ (the top half of the circle). I simplified this to be over $[0, d]$ = $\frac{\pi r^2}{12}$ (symmetry argument).

Evaluating the integral gives $0.5(x\sqrt{r^2-d^2} + r^2\arctan(\frac{d}{\sqrt{r^2-d^2}})$, which equals $\frac{\pi r^2}{12}$.

However, I cannot simplify this any further, i.e. $d$ = a function of $r$.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Note that the area of the central part (between $-d$ and $d$) is $$4\int_0^dydx$$ to include all four quadrants.

Comment: A closed expression seems unlikely, given the formula for the area of a [segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment#Area)

Comment: You have modelled the circle as a function of $x$ above. Let $A(x)$ be the area of the circle intersected with $\{(a,b) \}_{b \le x}$. So it is zero for $x \le -r$, the strictly increasing to $\pi r^2$ at $x=r$, and constant thereafter. You want to solve $A(x_k) = \frac{k}{n} \pi r^2$ for $k=1,...,n-1$ (You know $A(-r)=0$, $A(+r) = \pi r^2$). I doubt a closed form expression in 'elementary' functions can be found.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to look at it is this.  You are trying to identify [circular segments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) with area $\pi r^2/ n$, $2\pi r^2/ n$, etc.  In general, the area of a circular segment with half-angle $\theta$ is given by the area of the sector $(\theta r^2)$ minus the area of the central triangle ($r^2 \sin\theta \cos\theta$), so you need the solution to
$$
\theta-\sin\theta\cos\theta = \frac{\pi k}{n}
$$
for each $1 \le k \le n-1$.  As a function of $\theta$, the left-hand side increases monotonically from $0$ to $\pi$, so the solution will be unique for each value of $k/n$; it will generally not have a closed-form solution.  In terms of the angles $\theta_k$, the cuts must be made at $x_{k}=r\cos\theta_{k}$.